# UITextView didChangeSelection not getting called?

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have implemented the UITextViewDelegate in my view Controller, which needs to do something when the text selection changes in textView.

So I used `textview:didChangeSelection` to listen to call back events.  It works on the iPhone simulator and iOS5 ,but not on iPhone4 devices.  Why does that happen?

Debug information tells me that the `textview:didChangeSelection` isn't getting called when I change selection with range of 0 length....

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView.selectedRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        selectRange = textView.selectedRange;
    }
}
```

Can anyone can help to fix the problem?

Comment: u sure u added the UITextViewDelegate to a VIEWCONTROLLER u use? cause i added it to class which just had the text view and i ran in to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add UITextViewDelegate in your header file ?

Comment: yes ,i already add UITextViewDelegate in my header file,other callback functions such as textviewDidBeginEditing, textviewDidChage  works well, only textViewDidChangeSelection just not getting called in ios devices

Comment: This is very odd. Can you restart your device, delete the app and try clean Xcode build on it ?

Comment: I've try already,it doesn't work as well.but i found it's strange that "textViewDidChangeSelection" are getting called only when i double click the textView at the same position.
(only in ios4.2)